# C++ ofstream output to image file writes different data on Windows

Tags: c++, image, windows-7, ofstream

Im doing a simple thing: writing the data of an image file stored as a string into the image file containing that string.

```
std::ofstream f("image.jpeg");
f << image_data; // image_data was created using python and copied over, in hex and turned back into ascii
```

And yet, the unexpected happens:

[image: Good Picture]

becomes:

[image: Bad Picture]

I cannot understand why this is happening.

> When I use python2.7 to get the data from the original picture and write
>   it to a new file, it works fine.
>
> When I compile and run my program in ubuntu, the picture comes out
>   fine.
>
> When I write a large text file (larger than the image) into a .txt,
>   the file comes out fine.
>
> It is only jpegs on Windows that fails. The original image I tried was
>   an image from a PGP key packet, which came out with half of the
>   person's head clear and the other half messed up.

The compiled program doesnt mess up all of the data, since like I said above, some of the original picture is shown. Also, the images are the same size, so the jpeg format was preserved at least.

What is happening? I am using ming2 4.7.2 in Code::Blocks on Windows 7. Is Windows just being crazy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must open the file in binary mode:

```
std::ofstream f("image.jpeg", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
//                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks! But why does this work on Ubuntu, without `std::ios::binary`?

Comment: Maybe on windows, a `\n` is translated to `CR-LF`?

Comment: Well, that's windows for you. I'm also not sure whether any encoding-translation is done when writing files in text mode, e.g. ascii->latin1. Either way, text mode is evil for what you want to do.